# How to shard postgreSQL data using Django for a chat application?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using a Django based app server to run a chat application. In future a person can have more than thousands messages per user and so, my message table will blow up even after few million users.

How do I shard and manage that data using Django? Is there anything that Django provides to handle these things. What if my query required multiple shard to be accessed at same time. Will Django do that for me? If Django doesn't support it, how will I handle it in future?

Assuming, I have a foreign key to determine the sender of the message and a foreign key to the room(chat room) to which this message belongs to.

```
query1 = Message.objects.filter(created_at__gt=timestamp)
query2 = Message.objects.filter(id__lte=message_id).update(is_seen=True)
```

Also, what if I need to serialize a Room object and I want the last message object of that room. How will serializer handle that?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure that's something you want to be doing in Django?

Comment: I think people at Disqus and Instagram did this. So, I think if this is not much of a hassle? What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Use postgres sharding? https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-11-sharding.html

Comment: @DroidX86 Will this integerate with Django?

Comment: It's a postgres feature. I don't see why it won't

Comment: So basically. ORM queries will remain same and postgres will do the work to shard the data and manage it?

Comment: Think so. Read the official wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Built-in_Sharding before diving in

Comment: This is absolutely premature optimisation. The time to worry about this is when you do have a million users.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. I agree with you. I just don't want to do things now, which are irreversible in future. Although, I know there wont be any problem in this scenario but again to understand the architecture and how industry handle these things, I wanted to know it